# how do i render a partial view with new data using ajax post?

Tags: jquery, ajax, refresh, partial-views, actionresult

I'm trying to refresh a partial with new data using ajax.
i've used this function in javascript:

```
function replace{
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("DoThing", "Controller"),
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "actionresult",
        async: false,
        data: {itemCode: $("#ComboBox-input").val(), unitCode: @(Model.UnitCode)}
    });
}
```

And the controller action:

```
Public ActionResult DoThing(int itemCode, int unitCode)
{
    var aThing = new ExModel
                     {
                         ItemCode = itemCode,
                         UnitCode = unitCode
                     }
    return PartialView("_InPartial", aThing);
}
```

Now during debug i get to the controller action with the data i sent,
but i don't know how to render the partial view with the returned data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your partial has to be in an element which you can refer to in js, like this:

```
<div id="myPartialDiv"><!-- here your partial --></div>
```

Then, remove the datatype (not necessary) and add the success method which will put the server response (your rendered partial) in the div:

```
function replace{
   $.ajax({
       url: '@Url.Action("DoThing", "Controller")',
       type: "POST",
       async: false,
       data: {itemCode: $("#ComboBox-input").val(), unitCode: @(Model.UnitCode)},
       success: function(response){
           $('#myPartialDiv').html(response);
       }
    });
}
```

Usually you don't have to do this on your own, I think you will have your reasons.
But normally you should use [Ajax.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink.aspx) with [AjaxOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.aspx) where you set `UpdateTargetId` to myPartialDiv.